# Как упростить if?

Tags: python

Есть длинное условие:

```
if j==465 or j==641 or j==465 or j==641 or j==638 or j==637 or j==644 or j==645 or j==648 or j==1120 or j==1122 or j==1124 и т.д.
```

Можно его как-то упростить?

Answer (score 5):

Хранить все числовые значения в массиве, а if переписать так:

```
elements = [465, 641, ...]
if j in elements:
    #do something
```

Answer (score 5):

Для данного случая лучше использовать множества:

```
elements = frozenset([465,641,638,637,644,645,648,1120,1122,1124])
if j in elements:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if j in [465,641,638,637,644,645,648,1120,1122,1124]
```

Comment: Ну вот, 2 одинаковых ответа с разницей в 10 секунд)